# React production build 404 error on direct link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I am having a problem with my React application on production build. When I open a link directly, I get a 404 error. However, if I open the same link from the homepage, it works fine.

My application is live at https://shreejisecuresofttech.com/.

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import PrivacyPolicy from './PrivacyPolicy';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyPolicy />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am not sure what is causing this problem. I have tried several things, such as clearing my cache and cookies, but nothing has worked.

Additional information:

• I am using React Router v6.
• I am deploying my application to Nginx.

Comment: Presumably you lack the fall-back to index.html required for client-side "push state" routing. See e.g. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing for an explanation.

Comment: Do you mean I need to add this in head tag:
  <base href="https://example.com/">
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
      if (location.pathname === '/') {
        window.location.href = '/index.html';
      }
    });
  </script>

Comment: No (nowhere in what I linked does it suggest that) you need to configure your server correctly.

Comment: I can't find tutorial for Nginx I am not even using express only create-react-app and I tried specifng the homepage in your package.json as per link

Comment: Search e.g. "Nginx push state routing". It's unclear why you thought setting homepage _would_ work, it doesn't correspond to your use case. _Actually read_ the documentation.

Comment: I'm still confused about the initial problem. The link to the Privacy Policy page opens, but the anchor tag does not. All of my other pages open fine, return a 404 error after reloading once opened like /privacy-policy

Answer (score 0):

In the Public folder of your React project, create a file named `_redirects` (no extension at the last) and then write following line in the file -

```
/*     /index.html  200
```

Comment: ...do you think they're using [Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/)? That's not the same thing as NGINX.

Comment: I tried but still the same and I am on rhel linux